# Variadic template with printf argument checking

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-templates

I have a printf-style function that takes a variable number of arguments. Here is my starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void MyPrint (const char* fmt,...)
  {
  va_list arglist ;
  va_start (arglist, fmt) ;
  vprintf (fmt, arglist) ;
  va_end (arglist) ;
  }

int main()
  {
  MyPrint ("Hello, %s\n", "world") ;
  }
```

This prints `Hello, world` as expected.

Now I want to make two changes. First, I want to check the format string using the `format` attribute of g++. So I declare the `MyPrint` function first (I have to declare it first, because for some reason g++ doesn't let you assign attributes to a function definition):

```
void MyPrint (const char* fmt,...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))) ;
```

Now if I try e.g. `MyPrint ("Hello, %d\n", "world") ;` I get a nice error message.

The second change I want to make is to use a variadic template parameter. Like this:

```
#include <utility> // for std::forward
template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (Params&&... fmt)
  {
  printf (std::forward<Params> (fmt)...) ;
  }
```

This works too. So I combine the two, by adding the format-checking attribute to the variadic function template with this forward declaration:

```
template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (Params&&... fmt) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))) ;
```

But now I get this error message (gcc 10.2):

> <source>: In substitution of 'template<class ... Params> void MyPrint(Params&& ...) [with Params = {const char (&)[11], const char (&)[6]}]':
> <source>:15:38:   required from here
> <source>:8:6: error:
> 'format' attribute argument 2 value '1' refers to parameter type
> 'const char (&)[11]'

This has got me completely baffled. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility> // for std::forward

template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (Params&&... fmt) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))) ;

template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (Params&&... fmt) // <-- Line 8
  {
  printf (std::forward<Params> (fmt)...) ;
  }

int main()
  {
  MyPrint ("Hello, %s\n", "world") ; // <-- Line 15
  }
```

Comment: Does `std::forward` make any sense here?  It's going to be copied (and even promoted) to `printf` anyway. `The second change I want to make is to use a variadic template parameter` what for? What's the goal here?

Comment: @KamilCuk: "What's the goal here?" The function is actually a class constructor. I want derived classes to have similar variadic constructors, that can simply call the base class's constructor 'as is'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for info: this has been fixed in gcc 13.1. The program works as expected, with no compiler errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the first error go away by adding a fixed `const char *` argument as the format string and pointing the attribute to that.

```
template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (const char * format, Params&&... fmt) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2))) ;

template<typename...Params>
void MyPrint (const char * format, Params&&... fmt) // <-- Line 9
  {
  printf (format, std::forward<Params> (fmt)...) ;
  }
```

Which reveals another error:

```
test.cc:8:6: error: ‘format’ attribute argument 3 value ‘2’ does not refer to a variable argument list
    8 | void MyPrint (const char * format, Params&&... fmt) // <-- Line 9
      |      ^~~~~~~
```

It seems that the attribute for checking the `printf` archetype relies on one `const char *` argument and a variable argument list and is not willing to work without them. So you have to give up either the C++ template magic or the compile-time format string checking.

Comment: Is there a logical reason that this is impossible, do you think? Or is it just a shortcoming of the compiler? (I tried various compilers, but they all reject my code.)

Comment: I don't think it's impossible, it's just not supported. If you have a compelling argument why this would be useful, you can try raising it as a wishlist bug against gcc.